# ElasticSearch [script] unknown field [file], parser not found

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I used `script_score` to customize the scoring:

```
GET /customer/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "name": "Mark"
                }
            },
            "script_score": {
              "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "file": "test"
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I set `"file": "test"`, and put `test.groovy` file in `config/scripts` directory, but I got these error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "[script] unknown field [file], parser not found"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "[script] unknown field [file], parser not found"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

`[script] unknown field [file], parser not found`! Why? Should I need to install some plugins?

**Elasticsearch version** : 6.2.3

**Plugins installed**: None

**JVM version** : 1.8.0_181

**OS version**: Ubuntu Linux 4.4.0-124-generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[File scripts have been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/breaking_60_scripting_changes.html#_file_scripts_removed) in ES 6.0, you should now use [stored scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/modules-scripting-using.html#modules-scripting-stored-scripts) instead.

You can easily [migrate your Groovy script to Painless](https://qbox.io/blog/how-to-painless-scripting-in-elasticsearch).

First, store your script:

```
POST _scripts/test
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "Math.log(_score * 2)"
  }
}
```

Then use it in your query:

```
GET /customer/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "name": "Mark"
                }
            },
            "script_score": {
              "script": {
                "id": "test"
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to do some complicated strategy to calculate the score, can I store the script code to a file?

Comment: you can store it in a file, but ultimately you'll need to store it in ES using the `_scripts` endpoint