# CrateDB is failing to start

Tags: fiware, cratedb

After figuring everything out I am close to finish up this project but it seems the new crateDB version is failing to start. Here is my crate docker-compose.yml file:

```
crate:
          image: crate:4.1.4
          hostname: crate
          expose:
             - "4200"
             - "4300"
             - "5432"
          networks:
            - default
          ports:
            - "4200:4200"
            - "4300:4300"
            - "5432:5432"
          command:
            -Clicense.enterprise=false -Cauth.host_based.enabled=false -Ccl>
            -Chttp.cors.enabled=truue -Chttp.cors.allow-origin="*"
          environment:
            - CRATE_HEAP_SIZE=2g
```

And here is the exit code:

```
    srdjan-crate-1         | [2022-08-03T13:02:41,141][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [Schermerspitze] uncaught exception in thread [main]
srdjan-crate-1         | org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[java.io.IOException: failed to read /data/data/nodes/0/_state/node-2.st]; nested: IOException[failed to read /data/data/nodes/0/_state/node-2.st]; nested: XContentParseException[[-1:36] [node_meta_data] unknown field [node_version], parser not found];
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupExceptionProxy.<init>(StartupExceptionProxy.java:31) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.init(CrateDB.java:162) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.execute(CrateDB.java:138) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:82) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.0.0.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.0.0.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.main(CrateDB.java:91) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.main(CrateDB.java:84) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         | Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: java.io.IOException: failed to read /data/data/nodes/0/_state/node-2.st
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.ExceptionsHelper.maybeThrowRuntimeAndSuppress(ExceptionsHelper.java:158) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadGeneration(MetaDataStateFormat.java:416) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadLatestStateWithGeneration(MetaDataStateFormat.java:435) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadLatestState(MetaDataStateFormat.java:456) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.loadOrCreateNodeMetaData(NodeEnvironment.java:406) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:302) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:239) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at io.crate.node.CrateNode.<init>(CrateNode.java:63) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy$1.<init>(BootstrapProxy.java:184) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.setup(BootstrapProxy.java:184) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.init(BootstrapProxy.java:252) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.init(CrateDB.java:158) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    ... 6 more
srdjan-crate-1         | Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to read /data/data/nodes/0/_state/node-2.st
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadGeneration(MetaDataStateFormat.java:410) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadLatestStateWithGeneration(MetaDataStateFormat.java:435) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadLatestState(MetaDataStateFormat.java:456) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.loadOrCreateNodeMetaData(NodeEnvironment.java:406) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:302) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:239) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at io.crate.node.CrateNode.<init>(CrateNode.java:63) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy$1.<init>(BootstrapProxy.java:184) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.setup(BootstrapProxy.java:184) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.init(BootstrapProxy.java:252) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.init(CrateDB.java:158) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    ... 6 more
srdjan-crate-1         | Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentParseException: [-1:36] [node_meta_data] unknown field [node_version], parser not found
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.ObjectParser.getParser(ObjectParser.java:326) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.ObjectParser.parse(ObjectParser.java:150) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.ObjectParser.apply(ObjectParser.java:174) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeMetaData$1.fromXContent(NodeMetaData.java:110) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeMetaData$1.fromXContent(NodeMetaData.java:94) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.read(MetaDataStateFormat.java:303) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadGeneration(MetaDataStateFormat.java:406) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadLatestStateWithGeneration(MetaDataStateFormat.java:435) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadLatestState(MetaDataStateFormat.java:456) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.loadOrCreateNodeMetaData(NodeEnvironment.java:406) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:302) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:239) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at io.crate.node.CrateNode.<init>(CrateNode.java:63) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy$1.<init>(BootstrapProxy.java:184) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.setup(BootstrapProxy.java:184) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.init(BootstrapProxy.java:252) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.init(CrateDB.java:158) ~[crate-app.jar:4.1.4]
srdjan-crate-1         |    ... 6 more
srdjan-crate-1 exited with code 1
```

All i need is some data pushing container, I am using FIWARE tutorials and webinar in order to visualize my data, and the crateDB container always fails to start, I mean it starts but later it just goes off... any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

This is when i run docker inspect command:

```
 sudo docker inspect crate
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:33244aff8840432e394adcda8d92e07cfd3a7b33c63f5c39e51707c93aea3b55",
        "RepoTags": [
            "crate:5.0.0",
            "crate:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "crate@sha256:3da3f761952d46279cb35dd28d33f93fa36cce6cb7fe0dfb5d90e52d73c1d400"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2022-07-18T18:28:30.251880519Z",
        "Container": "b10af8c7173a0753094c02fcc75cfbfd712588870a727b7fce113d83734379b1",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "b10af8c7173a",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "4200/tcp": {},
                "4300/tcp": {},
                "5432/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/crate/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "CRATE_HEAP_SIZE=512M"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"crate\"]"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:0b000e181ffab1924c18f0d9b14f801d9c921747270d9400dbf0ed4bbd60dada",
            "Volumes": {
                "/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/data",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "Crate.io <office@crate.io>",
                "org.label-schema.build-date": "20201113",
                "org.label-schema.license": "GPLv2",
                "org.label-schema.name": "CentOS Base Image",
                "org.label-schema.schema-version": "1.0",
                "org.label-schema.vendor": "CentOS",
                "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2022-07-13T09:51:35.203197",
                "org.opencontainers.image.description": "CrateDB is a distributed SQL database that handles massive amounts of machine data in real-time.",
                "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "GPL-2.0-only",
                "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/crate/docker-crate",
                "org.opencontainers.image.title": "crate",
                "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://crate.io/products/cratedb/",
                "org.opencontainers.image.vendor": "Crate.io",
                "org.opencontainers.image.version": "5.0.0"
            }
        },
        "DockerVersion": "20.10.12",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "4200/tcp": {},
                "4300/tcp": {},
                "5432/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/crate/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "CRATE_HEAP_SIZE=512M"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "crate"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:0b000e181ffab1924c18f0d9b14f801d9c921747270d9400dbf0ed4bbd60dada",
            "Volumes": {
                "/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/data",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "Crate.io <office@crate.io>",
                "org.label-schema.build-date": "20201113",
                "org.label-schema.license": "GPLv2",
                "org.label-schema.name": "CentOS Base Image",
                "org.label-schema.schema-version": "1.0",
                "org.label-schema.vendor": "CentOS",
                "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2022-07-13T09:51:35.203197",
                "org.opencontainers.image.description": "CrateDB is a distributed SQL database that handles massive amounts of machine data in real-time.",
                "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "GPL-2.0-only",
                "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/crate/docker-crate",
                "org.opencontainers.image.title": "crate",
                "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://crate.io/products/cratedb/",
                "org.opencontainers.image.vendor": "Crate.io",
                "org.opencontainers.image.version": "5.0.0"
            }
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 835792459,
        "VirtualSize": 835792459,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "RootDir": "/mnt/docker-data/overlay/b7ac674f087e8ed9cc8c1739dfc5e89186bdd95d5e1be27b22cc0220311a39f6/root"
            },
            "Name": "overlay"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:174f5685490326fc0a1c0f5570b8663732189b327007e47ff13d2ca59673db02",
                "sha256:0d4a826419c2dbb52dc24a4014281a339ec6fdb9ca2f0d5fd06c704c1d93f967",
                "sha256:8969ec2851837211e98eccf1295c27dc1de127f34bc258fa483147783c12589a",
                "sha256:4e669d13da98c64a63c1b4d342e1268b7134804f8060b4bbcd00cf44be59093b",
                "sha256:1e6365a3e5763f9d18849913accb29b3b938b934bc30d193fc6c2b73cea46345",
                "sha256:bd8cdcad9e0050447018c5f0c7dee8dcb2d27bc7b2ab4dcc0ca5d77c2e342dc8",
                "sha256:0add4659d3892065ce42055bef93cf56a1c8c1b7ea335dfe0add0899ae0437c3",
                "sha256:5321d2882bd76b170c6b93cce450679c204d520704c906c09ebf089ee5e93e3b"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Still can't find a way to start it, i looked all the other issues and i changed the memory and it still fails... Any help will be appreciated :), My OS is Linux Mint

Comment: Update, i tried to increase the memory with this command : sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
But it still fails to start

Comment: This is my java version: openjdk version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.3+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Your error message has a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869270/elasticsearch-script-unknown-field-file-parser-not-found) - That is an elasticsearch error, so remove that container for now.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the heads up solved it!